# Как сделать выдачу ролей через определенное время Discord py

Tags: python, discord

Я пытаюсь создать бота, который будет выдавать роль по активности в голосовом канале.
Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу понять, как сделать так чтобы роль выдавалась пользователю, только тогда, когда он будет общаться в голосовом канале минимум 1 час.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.
Желательно, чтобы это было прописано через @bot.event
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: ну так считайте сколько пользователь провёл в голосовом канале без выкл микро

Comment: @Merka и как это сделать?

Comment: считайте сколько пользователь провёл в голосовом канале без выключенного микро. При обновлении базы данных(или там где вы храните время) сверяйте сколько всего прошло, если прошёл 1ч, то выдавайте роль